# Autodesk forge : move pivot/3D manipulator (cutting tool) on element

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm trying to move pivot but without success.
I have done some tests with funtion "setPivotPoint()" :

```
viewer3D.utilities.setPivotPoint(newPivot);
```

But I don't manage to move it exactly where I want.

Is there a trick to set/center pivot on element (via dbId for example) ?
Thanks for help.

**Edit:**
I think I misunderstood what the pivot was.
I'm looking to move this:
[3D manipulator with cutting tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nloiX.png)

Answer (score 0):

The section tool extension exposes a method called `setSectionFromPlane` that you can use to define a custom plane. For example, to set the plane to face in direction (1,1,1) and go through the origin, use the following code:

```
const extension = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.Section');
extension.setSectionFromPlane(new THREE.Vector4(1,1,1,0));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have error when I test your code. Not a lot of time right now, I will investigate later and come back.

Comment: Any luck with this @JulienC? Btw. this code snippet can only be run *after* the viewer has been initialized.